# Finding cycles in a (not quite) Latin square

Tags: algorithm, permutation, cycle-detection

Given a matrix of size `m X n` with no repetition of values in rows or columns, is there an efficient method of detecting cycles?

For example, here is a sample matrix:

> 3  5  2  9  7  4
>    4  3  6  1  8  7
>    1  4  7  5  2  9
>    9  8  3  2  6  1
>    2  6  8  7  3  5

It has at least one permutation cycle of size 3:

> 3  5  2  9  7  4
>      4  **8**  **3**  1  **6**  7
>      1  4  7  5  2  9
>      9  **6**  **8**  2  **3**  1
>      2  **3**  **6**  7  **8**  5

The values 3, 6, and 8 in rows 2, 4 and 5 form a cycle.

The problem relates to [Kakuro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakuro) puzzles.  Nothing to do with solving them, but trying to detect whether any layout of a particular grid makes it unsuitable. A cycle of any sort would make that particular layout invalid - since the sum of rows and columns is the same for both layouts.

Comment: How values 3, 6 and 8 form a cycle? can you explain more? I cannot see any relation with 3, 6 and 8.

Comment: @PhamTrung: I think it is this: When you remove the first, fourth and last columns and the first and third rows, you get a Latin square with the numbers 3, 6 and 8.

Comment: @MOehm thanks, now I see some connections, and if we rotate 3, 6, and 8 in one row, we also get the next permutation of the next rows.

Comment: Yes, M Oehm is exactly right.  And I got the row numbers wrong which wouldn't have helped.  And thanks to my mystery editor.

Comment: I notice that 2 and 7 on rows 1 and 3 is a "cycle" too.

Comment: Yes I just found it when testing a simple brute-force search!  Well spotted.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write a full answer, but I've thought of an O(nmk2^k) algorithm, with k the largest matrix entry.  Exponential in k, but very fast if k <= 9 :)  The set of numbers along the top row of a cycle must equal the set of numbers along the leftmost column, so for each possible top-left corner (i, j), we can intersect the numbers to its right with the numbers below it to find the set of (<= k) *candidate numbers* C to include alongside x[i,j].  Then try all 2^k subsets of them (sometimes using tricks to eliminate them faster, that I think will apply very frequently).

Comment: I've just got a version going. For a given cycle length _p_ and tlc position _(r, c)_, I take every possible col- and row- set combination for completing the cycle, of which there are _C(n-r, p-1)_ possibilities for each. That gives me every distinct candidate-cell matrix. I then count the number of different values _d_ in that set. If _d = p_ then it must be a cycle. This seems to be independent of the number of symbols _k_.

Comment: That sounds OK, but the sum of C(n-r, p-1) over all values of p is already O(2^(n-r)) -- and you will actually be summing C(n-r, p-1)^2 over all values of p, which is much larger. Although I wrote O(2^k) for using symbol subsets as I suggested, this is also O(2^(n-r)) (after the O(k) merge step to find the intersection). The advantage of using symbol subsets (plus TLC) over row and column subsets (plus TLC) is twofold: (1) A symbol that appears in the intersection I described simultaneously determines a row *and* column, so there are only O(2^(n-r)) choices to try. (2) ...

Comment: ... Given a symbol subset C, you can instantly rule out a symbol c if the entry at (row(c, tlc), col(c, tlc)) is not in C.  This will occur often, and will often lead to cascades of symbols being eliminated from contention at a particular TLC.  (Here "row(c, tlc)" means "the unique row at or below tlc that contains symbol c in the leftmost column", and "col(c, tlc)" means "the unique column at or to the right of tlc that contains symbol c in the topmost row" -- these can be easily precomputed in O(nmk) time.)

Comment: Another trick is that for some given TLC, if there is any c in C such that the x[row(c, tlc), col(c, tlc)] = x[TLC], then you can immediately stop -- since this means you have a 2x2 cycle, whose top-left and bot-right entries are x[TLC], and whose opposite corners are c. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in O(n^3) time, for an n x n grid.

**Idea**

Consider your example grid, and hypothesize whether the topleft 3 and 5 can end up in a latin sub-square.

```
(3) (5)  2   9   7   4
 4   8   3   1   6   7
 1   4   7   5   2   9
 9   6   8   2   3   1
 2   3   6   7   8   5
```

Because we want a latin square, we're forced to include that 3 in the (5) column (all values must appear in each column), and also the nearby 2 (must form a square):

```
(3) (5)  2   9   7   4
 4   8   3   1   6   7
 1   4   7   5   2   9
 9   6   8   2   3   1
(2) (3)  6   7   8   5
```

We can keep doing this implication for awhile, but we'll soon run into a problem: the left row doesn't contain a 5. Including the top-left 3 and the top-left 5 leads to a contradiction.

In general, anytime we include 2 values in the same row or the same column, that pair will force up to 4 other values to be included and/or will imply a contradiction. We want to play with this implication structure to quickly eliminate bad solutions, leaving only good ones.

**Make a Graph**

Since we have this useful implication structure, we should explore it. Create a node for each horizontal and vertical pair of values, and insert directed edges between those nodes whenever a pair implies another pair must be included. Also have a node for "contradiction". For example, the `{(0, 0), (0, 1)}` pair corresponding to the top-left `(3) (5)` in the example would have outgoing edges to `{(0, 0), (4, 0)}`, `{(0, 1), (4, 1)}`, and `contradiction`.

The result is a graph with a lot of nodes pointing at contradiction and, potentially, some nodes pointing at each other in a cycle. Rip out the contradiction node and anything that points to it directly or indirectly, and all that's left should be the cycles and any cycle should correspond to a latin square.

**Correctness**

I'm honestly not sure if this is correct. It's clear that the latin square is *not* being immediately exhaustively checked for correctness in the sense of each added pair causing all the necessary work to happen... but I think all the bad cases that would be missed are ones where a value is duplicated and that was guaranteed not to happen in the input.

More work needed.

**Complexity**

There are O(n^3) nodes in the graph because there are O(n^2) pairs in a row or column, and O(n) rows+columns. There are also O(n^3) edges because each node has at most 4 out-edges.

Removing things pointing at `contradiction` takes time proportional to the number of nodes, assuming you're using edge lists. Just do a backwards flood-fill, following in-edges upstream.

Detecting a cycle takes time proportional to the number of nodes and edges: bucket nodes based on the number of out-nodes they have (at most 4), and keep removing nodes in the 0-out bucket and re-bucketing the affected nodes until done. If there's anything left, it's a cycle.

Since all operations take time proportional to the number of nodes and edges, and we have O(n^3) nodes+edges, the overall algorithm takes O(n^3) time.